# Batch exporting the render of the Freestyle SVG Export using python (to get a SVG vector file)

Tags: python, svg

Batch exporting the render of the **Freestyle SVG Export using python** (**to get a SVG vector file**)

**I know how to export a JPG:**

```
jpg_path = os.path.join(destination_path, name + '.jpg')
so.modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Input_12"] = jpg_path #update filename in image
            
#output to jpg file
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.render.image_settings.file_format='JPEG'
scene.render.filepath=jpg_path
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=1)
```

**I know how to export a STL:**

```
#output to stl file
stl_path = os.path.join(destination_path, name +'.stl')
bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath=stl_path,use_selection=True)
```

How does one do this for the **Freestyle SVG Export render using python** to get the **SVG** file with a **different name**? **it keeps adding 0000 to it.**

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Still looking for a solution.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Yes.  Thanks!